# Source code for hadoop commands

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'd like to see the source code for certain hadoop commands like -put and -ls. I want to be able to add additional information to the log outputs that are associated with running these commands.

How can I find these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source can be found in [Apache's SVN](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/).

You'll see files such as [Ls.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/Ls.java?view=markup), [CopyCommands.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/CopyCommands.java?view=markup) (defines -put, -copyFromLocal), etc.,  that all define the HDFS commands that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for being specific. For the record, I was doing searches inside my hadoop directory and I found the source files there, but what I was really after were the names of the source files for specific shell commands.

Comment: With update the link given above is no longer valid and now they can be found in [Haddop's Github](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell).